# Update Hero image when user changes filter

Tags: views

Struggling a little bit here and I hope this makes sense. I'm putting together a Blog is page generated by a view. The blog posts are assigned to categories (Taxonomy Terms). I've added a contextual filter which lists the categories and updates the blog posts with Ajax (Under theme -> Advanced). What I'd like to do us update the Hero image at the top of the page when the user clicks on a category. So as well as updating the blog posts it updates the Hero image.

I've created a new Hero Image view which has a contextual filters and is limited to one post, which i've included on my blog page view inside the header. Which is pulling in the hero image.

[image: Hero Image View]

I'm not sure whether I need to setup some sort of relationship between the Hero Image view and the Blog page view so the Hero image updates when you change the Contextual Filter.

Here is a screenshot of my Blog view:
[image: Blog View]

Hope the above makes sense.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: In the block, is the Main Image a field of the taxonomy vocabulary, and if so, did you assign in the taxonomy vocabulary itself a different image per term?

Comment: Yeah the blog that's being included in the header of the view is a field from the taxonomy term. I've added a custom field. Which i've added an image for each term.

Comment: Ok good! so 2 questions: 1) what is the URL you are using to test? and 2) why do you need the Filter criteria =Tags... you already have the contextual filter set up?